# Empty cell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am using Core Data in my app. When I run my app if internet connection is enabled i get data from service, remove all data and add new. But each time when I run my app in offline mode I see empty cell in my table view. I dont know the reason but when i get data from service for example if there are 3 items it adds 3 and plus one empty. Thats why i see one (sometimes one more) empty cell and 3 cells with items in my table view. Here is my code below

```
func product (token : NSString, code : NSString) {

    let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    var params : Dictionary = ["token" : token, "code" : code]
    self.deleteAllInCoreData()
    manager.GET(url, parameters: params, success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject) in

        println("JSON: " + responseObject.description)

        var response = responseObject.objectForKey("response") as? NSString

        if response == "true" {

            var responseDict = responseObject.objectForKey("products") as! NSArray

            for (index, value) in enumerate(responseDict) {

                var item = responseDict[index] as! NSDictionary
                var id = item.objectForKey("id") as! NSString
                var status = item.objectForKey("status") as! NSString
                var productName = item.objectForKey("product_name") as! NSString

                self.saveItem(productName as! String, itemStatus: status.boolValue, itemId: id as! String, action: "0")

            }
         self.tableView.reloadData()

    }, failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in

        println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)

    })

}
```

and

```
func saveItem(itemName: String, itemStatus: Bool, itemId: String, action : String)
{
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Items",
        inManagedObjectContext:
        managedContext)

    let itemObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

    itemObject.setValue(itemName, forKey: "productName")
    itemObject.setValue(itemStatus, forKey: "productStatus")
    itemObject.setValue(action, forKey: "action")
    itemObject.setValue(itemId, forKey: "productId")

    var error: NSError?
    if !managedContext.save(&error) {
        println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
    }

    items.append(itemObject)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This empty cell you see is a so called tableFooterView.
You can remove this empty cell by using :

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
```

Also, I'm not sure if that's also a problem you have, but at the moment you remove the data each time you call the `product` method. Are you really sure that you want to do that and not just if you are able to get newer data?

Answer (score 0):

```
for index in items {
    if (index.valueForKey("productName") == nil) {
        items.removeAtIndex(count)
    } else {
        count = count + 1
    }
}
```